# Tool to compare function signature to docstring

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, signature, docstring, code-documentation

Is there a tool that can check if the arguments listed in the docstring match the signature of the function call? It should be able to deal with numpy-style docstrings.
I am regularly using R CMD CHECK, which finds documentation/code mismatches in R and this is quite helpful. It would be very good to have something similar in Python, but I did not find anything yet.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to check the name and type of the parameters, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it should check that the name and type of the arguments in the documentation match the ones in the code.

Comment: In the case of Python the tools used for static checks of the docstrings against the signatures are [linters](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=linter+python), with [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) being one popular choice. Each IDE has a default linter and some IDE's like PyCharm use their proprietary linter implementation. This is probably a case of you not using an IDE that's set for Python, or not having configured a linter for Python (so it's an IDE config question). Finally, docs is another matter, see [Python-Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-sphinx/info).

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code, and I have pylint enabled. It gives me a ton of warnings, but it has never raised a docstring-code mismatch.

Answer (score 5):

I just created a tool to achieve this, called [`pydoctest`](https://github.com/jepperaskdk/pydoctest).

It will attempt to infer the types in your docstrings (not just lexically compare) and report back on mismatches between number of arguments, argument-names, argument-types, return-types, (optionally) throw error if lacking docstring and more.

It currently supports google, sphinx and numpy docstring format, but can rather easily be extended with other formats.

Example:

```
def func_type_mismatch(self, a: int) -> int:
    """[summary]

    Args:
        a (float): [description]        <-- float is not int

    Returns:
        int: [description]
    """
    pass
```

Running pydoctest on this function, gives this output:

`Function: <function IncorrectTestClass.func_type_mismatch at 0x7f9a8b52c8c8> FAIL | Argument type differ. Argument 'a' was expected (from signature) to have type '<class 'int'>', but has (in docs) type '<class 'float'>'`

Edit (June 2021): I've started the development of a vscode-extension that uses and highlights the errors.
[image]
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JeppeRask.pydoctest

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the same, so I wrote [docsig](https://github.com/jshwi/docsig)

`pip install docsig`

then just run `docsig .` and it will check this for you

```
/path/to/project
-----------------------
def function(✖*args) -> ✓List[str]:
    """...

    :param None: ✖
    :return: ✓
    """

E103: parameters missing
```

There are 8 other errors so far

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [pydoctest](https://pypi.org/project/pydoctest/) and [docsig](https://pypi.org/project/docsig/) mentioned in other answers, there are at least these tools:

- [pydoclint](https://github.com/jsh9/pydoclint) together with
  [pydocstyle](https://www.pydocstyle.org/) or [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff/)
- Pylint's [docparams extension](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/checkers/extensions.html#parameter-documentation-checker)
- [flake8-docstrings-complete](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-docstrings-complete/)
- [darglint2](https://github.com/akaihola/darglint2) (prohibitively slow for large projects)